# How to Retrive The Particular Book Details From Google My Library Through ID

Tags: javascript, json, api

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
      function handleResponse(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];
        // in production code, item.text should have the HTML entities escaped.
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" +item.volumeInfo.title+"<br>"+item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
      }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/buc0AAAAMAAJ"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I am Trying to Get Details of The Book Through Specific ID from the Google Books Please Help in JavaScript and JSON

Comment: Can you specify a little more what you want to do?

Comment: Sir i am trying get specfic book through ID of it but i am getting whole volume releated to it

Comment: Right now your are search the book which has or contains the word "orthopedics". Therefore all the book related to that is showing up. That why I asked you to specify. Do you want the book with the name "orthopedics" only.

Comment: Sir Orthopedics is the Volume ID But i am trying to get them through book ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the information about a particular book by making xhr request. I have created a function which return title and thumbanil of particular Book ID:

```
function getBookDetails(id) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/" + id;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var item = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.volumeInfo.title + "<br>" + "<img src=\""+item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail+"\" >";
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

getBookDetails("buc0AAAAMAAJ");
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypzzy3cd/1/)**

Comment: sir is that possible to retrive the particular public bookshelf books like in this way

Comment: Don't call me sir, call me Gaurav instead. You just need to get the link of the bookshelf and then use xhr request from the link , parse it and showcase it. This [link](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/bookshelves/list) will be helpful. If have any doubts, just ask.